# Order By a date field not working in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

I am trying to get data sorted by date with DESC, but always I am getting it with ASC, 
I tried 2 ways but there is no good result:

I have this repository :

```
@Repository
public interface CollectRepository extends JpaRepository<Collect, Long>
```

1st way, I used the sorting in @query:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Collect c LEFT JOIN c.payee p WHERE p.userId=:userId AND c.date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate ORDER BY c.date DESC")
List<Collect> getCollectionHistory(@Param("userId") String userId, 
                                   @Param("startDate") Date startDate, 
                                   @Param("endDate") Date endDate);
```

2nd way, I used the Sort

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Collect c LEFT JOIN c.payee p WHERE p.userId=:userId AND c.date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
List<Collect> getCollectionHistory(@Param("userId") String userId, 
                                   @Param("startDate") Date startDate, 
                                   @Param("endDate") Date endDate, Sort sort);
```

and calling the function using :

```
collectionList = collectRepository.getCollectionHistoryByCollector(userId, startDate, endDate, new Sort(Direction.DESC, "date"));
```

Collect Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "collect")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ", sequenceName = "collect_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "collect_id", nullable = false))
public class Collect extends GenericEntity {

    @Column(name = "collector_user_id")
    private String collectorUserId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "payer")
    private Payer payer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "payee")
    private Payee payee;

    @Column(name = "amount", precision = 5)
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Column(name = "date", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @JsonSerialize(using = IsoDateSerializer.class)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "reason")
    private String reason;

    @Column(name = "reference")
    private String reference;

// getters and setters
```

Payee Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "payee")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ", sequenceName = "payee_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "payee_id", nullable = false))
public class Payee extends GenericEntity {

    private String userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "payee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Collect> collects;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "payee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<PayeePayer> payeePayers;
```

I am using Spring Data JPA version : 1.10.5.RELEASE

is it a bug or I have something wrong in my code ? 
How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: add the code of Collect entity

Comment: I added the entity @MaciejKowalski

Comment: where is your userId?

Comment: @Spartan add Payee entity for perfect answer

Comment: I added the Payee entity @xenteros

Comment: @Spartan you have working example in my answer

Comment: whats the type of Date?

Comment: Out of topic but why the user ID is a String anyway?

Comment: @ngc4151 because I am using an external User Management, I am using Auth0 and it generates the ID users as a string

Comment: Are you modifying the list after fetching it from the database?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan yeah I am modifying the list because I have the Users IDs must be changed with their names

Comment: @AshishLohia all entities are extending a generic entity that contains the generated Id column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following method will return a List of `Collect` with `date` between `start` and `end` and `payee` with id `payeeId`. Once you add `Payee` to the question I can adjust to the model.

```
List<Collect> findAllByPayeeUserIdAndDateBetweenOrderByDateDesc(String payeeUserId, Date start, Date end);
```

Comment: your function is not working, I already tried this way in other service and it's not working also

Comment: @Spartan do you have a List or a Set? Set is unordered

Comment: sure I have a List

Comment: that's why I am asking  if it's a bug in the framework or not to migrate for a newer version if needed, there no exceptions not errors, all data sorted with ASC I think it's sorted by the ID of the rows

Comment: @Does it correctly limit rows by userId and date between?

Comment: all ways are giving me the right list but the problem only on Sorting

Comment: could you turn on logging all sql and paste the query which is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
List<Collect> findByPayeeUserIdAndDateBetweenOrderByDateDesc(String payeeUserId, Date start, Date end);
```

or

```
List<Collect> findByPayeeUser_IdAndDateBetweenOrderByDateDesc(String payeeUserId, Date start, Date end);
```

For the 2nd one, i have a similar repository of one of my project and it is like this:

```
import com.buhane.property.domain.entity.Lease;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface LeaseRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Lease, Long> {
    Page<Lease> findByApplicationId(Long applicationId, Pageable page);

    Page<Lease> findByApplicationProperty_Id(Long propertyId, Pageable page);

    List<Lease> findByApplicationIdAndActiveTrue(Long applicationId);
}
```

Please notice the line

```
Page<Lease> findByApplicationProperty_Id(Long propertyId, Pageable page);
```

and it is working fine :)

Comment: I already tried the 1st, but the 2nd will not work because I have to follow the names of the fields on the entities not in the database

Comment: @Spartan please see my updated answer, you might be wrong about the 2nd one.

Comment: you are using Pageable that's another way, but for my case I am not using pages yet, and for your case, you are naming Property_Id like that in the Lease entity

Comment: @Spartan No, actually my Lease entity has a reference to Application entity which has a reference to Property entity with "PropertyId" not "Property_Id". And my Property entity has a PK column which is just only "Id".